Angular Material Advanced Filtering resources
New to angular. I want to play around with creating advanced filtering for my app. Is there any resources that would help me create a UI in material With a column, filter,value that can be or'ed or and'ed

I found a resource here: https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/advanced-filtering#angular-grid-advanced-filtering-example but that is using ignite.
